# Parse.com [Javascript API] : Get an array of parse objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

So I'm working on a project with javascript and parse.com where each user will be associated with a facility.  Each facility has their own number so I have an array with those facility numbers in the user's object.  When that user logs in, there will be an array with those facility numbers that I need to make a query with.  I looked at the docs and saw a log of querying with arrays but they didn't seem to fit my needs.

I want an array back with each facility object from the facility table.  Here's a quick chart of the class structures:

User:`[userInfo(username, pass, etc]|[facilities(array)]`

Facilities:`[facilityName]|[facilityNumber]|[etc]`

So the user could be associated with multiple facilities.  I need to take the array of facility numbers and get back an array of those facilities.  So `facilities` could be `[1,2,11]` and it would give back three different facility objects in an array.

I tried this:

```
function loadFacilities(user) {

    var facilitiesArray = user.get("facilities");

    var query = queryWithClassName("facilities");

    query.equalTo("facilityNumber", facilitiesArray);

    query.find().then(function (results) {

        console.log(results);

    });

}
```

Knowing I would most likely get a `400 bad request` error because `facilityNumber` is a number, not an array like `facilities`.

So what's the best way to go at this.  I can easily create a query for each entry in the `facilities` array but that is very inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply replace your `equalTo` with `containedIn`:

```
query.containedIn("facilityNumber", facilitiesArray);
```

Documentation here:
http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#containedIn